# django user authentication and authorization

Tags: python, django, security, authentication

I need suggestion on the following issue, actually I start developing a small erp in django. I’m quite confuse about how to handle user authentication and authorization. My project architecture is

   ERP (Main Project)
o   HR (App)
o   Finance (App)
o   Payroll (App)
o   Sale (App)

How to implement login system in above architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Django has a nice and well documented login system. Is there a reason it does not fit your needs?

Comment: actually i;m new django and not fully cleared it to me.